# Invertir bits en un entero en Java

Tags: java, matemáticas

¿Cuál es la mejor manera para invertir un bit de un número entero en Java? He probado de la siguiente manera aunque me parece poco elegante:

```
    int entero = 4+2+1;

    if ((entero & 4) == 4)
        entero -= 4; 
    else
        entero += 4;

    System.out.println ("Entero con el bit 3 invertido: " + entero);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma habitual de invertir bits es usando el operador binario **xor** (`^`) junto con la *máscara* apropiada. En tu caso:

```
entero ^= 4
```

Comment: En java 7 se puede poner en binario, `entero ^= 0B100`, que es mucho más claro para un xor.